# Making multiple buffer, one with field values, one with a fixed value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, buffer

I use ArcGIS 10.2.2 Basic.

I have a point shapefile with a field called buffer with different values, depending of what kind of type the point is. Some of these points also need an extra buffer outside the buffer from the buffer field. This value is set at 5 meter.

I can't find any tool that lets me do a multiple buffer, with a field value and a fixed value.

So what I do, is that I create a buffer for the whole set, with FIELD Buffer as the value:

[image: After normal buffering]

I then export all features that need the extra buffer of 5 meter, into a set of it's own, and do a Multiple Ring Buffer with 5 meter on it:

[image]

The purple circles are now just increased in size. I want them to have a ring outside its first buffer value, with 5 meter. My ideally thought is the one you get out from multiple ring buffer, with 2 ObjectID's:

[image]

And, at the end, I want to merge the polygons that didnt need the 5 meter buffer togehter with the ones who did.

Is this not possible with different buffer sizes in a data set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't create a buffer with the buffer distances set manually and also by a field in the same step. The simplest solution is the one you're already using in your screenshots: adding the 5m buffer after you've created the others, then merging the two buffer layers. You just need to change a setting in the Buffer tool to create the type of buffer you want (a ring outside your original buffers).

In the Buffer tool, change the Side Type to OUTSIDE_ONLY:

[image]

As the name implies, that will create buffers only on the outside of the input features (the original buffer polygons in your case).

Comment: Additional question: How do i differentiate the outside buffer (5 meter)? The 5 meters are only as a "hazardious zone", so I would like to mark them as such. Do I have to manually edit every name in a column from i.e Tower to hazardious zone?

Comment: @2013US10 no, you can use the Field Calculator to edit many records in a table in one step.